# iOS Data Protection: What is the Input of the LFSR?

Tags: encryption, initialization-vector, lfsr

> Every time a file on the data partition is created, Data Protection creates a new 256-bit
>   key (the “per-file” key) and gives it to the hardware AES engine, which uses the key to
>   encrypt the file as it is written to flash memory using AES CBC mode. The initialization
>   vector (IV) is the output of a linear feedback shift register (LFSR) calculated with the
>   block offset into the file, encrypted with the SHA-1 hash of the per-file key.

Regarding [the iOS-Security whitepaper](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2012/readings/ios-security-may12.pdf) (excerpt from pg. 8) when a file is written to the data partition a AES-Key is created which is used by the AES engine to encrypt the file using the AES-CBC mode. AES-CBC does need an initialization vector which is the output of a linear feedback shift register.

- What is the exact input of the LFSR?
- What exactly does "block offset" mean?

Does it work like this:

> encrypt(LFSR(block-offset),SHA-1(perfile-key)) ---> result stored
>   inside the files meta data

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/dotclear/public/publications/11-hitbamsterdam-iphonedataprotection.pdf), which looked at it in detail, and they also implemented [tools](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dataprotection/) to do it, it works as follows (roughly):

Every protected file has a metadata entry that contains its encrypted per-file key, and this per-file key is encrypted with its corresponding class key; the metadata also contains information about the protection class of the file. The metadata field itself is also encrypted, with the EMF-key. The file data itself is encrypted only with the per-file key, and the IV is implicit, i.e. not part of that data (quoting from [this followup on iOS 5](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/iOS-5-data-protection-updates)):

> To compute the IV for a block in a file data fork, the input to the IV
>   generator is now the block offset in the file fork (instead of the
>   block LBA on iOS 4), and the resulting IV is then encrypted (AES128)
>   with the "IV-key" to give the actual IV. The "IV-key" is unique
>   per-file and computed using the following formula:
>
> IV-key = SHA1(filekey)[:16]

This is probably to ensure that if different file-system blocks in a file are identical (maybe blocks of 0) the IV's used for those blocks are entirely different (they used to be just the block LBA on iOS 4 fed through an LSFR). The IV generator (from the block offset) is still the same LSFR though (and its source can be found among the mentioned tools).